# How to add uitoolbar to uitableviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have an UITableViewController which I would like to add UIToolbar to with one button. In the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
```

method of UITableViewController I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton1:)];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Some title";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
 }
```

Unfortunately I don't see the toolbar when I run my app.
Any hints? Should I do something more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navigationItem` property of a view controller is useless if that controller is not displayed inside a `UINavigationController`.
If your view controller is inside a navigation controller I don't know what the problem is.
Otherwise you can use an `UINavigationItem` but you need to create a `UINavigationBar` yourself.
Either in the Interface Builder (add a `UINavigationBar` and add a `UINavigationItem`, then connect the `UINavigationItem` to a property outlet declared your view controller (you don't need to connect the Bar).
Or in your code :

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                             target:self action:@selector(pressButton1:)];

UINavigationItem* navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
navItem.title = @"Your title";

naviBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
naviBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
naviBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0);
[self.view addSubview:naviBar];
[navItem release];
```

Comment: That was it! I had no idea that I need to create UINavigationItem. I thought that UITableView has already one. Thanks @FenchKiss Dev!

Answer (score 2):

Your method requires an autorelease:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(pressButton1:)] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Some title";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
 }
```

There's nothing wrong with your code per se. Your question states you want to add an UIToolBar to your view? Really? Or do you just want to add a button to the NavigationItem for UITableView?

Comment: Thanks Jordan!
In the beginning I wanted to have UIToolbar in my view togeether with UITable View, but later on I figured out that I could leverage the NavigationItem from UITTableViewController and I came out with the code above. If there is nothing wrong, then any ideas why I don't see the toolbar?

Comment: Do you check your IB Connections? What does show? Maybe you can post some code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *have* to use a UITableViewController and are not using a UINavigationController in your app already, you can set your view controller up as a regular UIViewController with a toolbar and tableview.

To do this in IB, drag out a UIViewController object and add a toolbar and tableview. Hook up outlets for both and set the delegate and datasource of the tableview to Files Owner. Add any other toolbar items or buttons and give them outlets and methods if you need them for buttons, etc. In your ViewController.h file, make sure you sign it up to conform to the UITableViewDataSource and UITabBarDelegate:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarDelegate>
```

From there, just build out your tableview delegate and datasource methods like you normally would, and write your button action methods for any buttons you added to the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't show the toolbar.  It is hidden by default.  To fix it, you just put this line of code:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

I tried it and it worked.  Just make sure that you put in the implementation file's viewDidLoad method.